# learning javascript, why code will not work for javascript

Tags: javascript

I use IE 11 with the scripting option enabled.  Even on other browsers it does not work.  Using notepad++ to code and run... I'm currently learning javascript.  I have a .js and .html file - the html has 3 sets of headings/paragraphs where the paragraphs should only show if i click the headings.  This does not work.  I downloaded a copy of the java library as well...  I assume it has something to do with the Doctype statement ?
Any thoughts:

**mcode.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("p").hide();

  $("h1").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
  });

});
```

myhtml.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Demo</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
 <h1>Heading one</h1>
 <p>This is just some text for heading 1</p>

 <h1>Heading two</h1>
 <p>This is just some text for heading 2</p>

 <h1>Heading three</h1>
 <p>This is just some text for heading 3</p>

<!-- FIRST BELOW POINTS TO WHERE THE JAVA SCRIPT LIBRARY IS   -->
<!-- SECOND IS MY JAVASCRIPT CODE THAT WILL BE USED           -->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_code.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check what the browser console has to say.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Do you have the jquery libary in the same directory as your html file? Do you have any console errors?

Comment: Works fine for me. I would suggest using an IDE to develop, makes things a lot easier than just using notepad.

Comment: Also I recommend to step away from xhtml. Html5 is far better and a well accepted standard these days.

Comment: Check the name of your JavaScript file, your comments say mcode.js but the HTML has an underscore. Also those two JavaScript files must be in the same location as you have it now.

Comment: in fact the mycode.js vs. my_code.js was the issue - appreciate the help - I'm a newbie unfortunately green in terms of html/css/javascript/c# as I'm learning it all now... but this problem I should have seen.

Answer (score 2):

You have listed your javascript as mcode.js in the question, but referenced src="my_code.js". Change your src in the html to the correct file and it should work fine.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="mcode.js"></script>`

That should be what you are after :)

Comment: To increase your reputation, you might consider further filling out your profile.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add mcode.js in your html file. Add a script in your head linked to mcode.js.

Comment: Oof these comments are aggressive. OP links a file called `my_code.js` but refers to js file as `mcode.js` in the question. Assuming his code works fine, then this answer, while it could use more elaboration, isn't unhelpful. :/

Comment: I'm not allowed to comment